# How can Store MultiData Value in a Struct and work with Them?

Tags: c, struct

my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*
    struct Value {
       int typ;
       unsigned char vstring;
       int   vint;
       float  vfloat;
    };
*/
struct Value {
   int typ;
   /*
   type=1  ==> get vstring
   type=2  ==> get int
   type=3  ==> get float
   */
   union{
      struct{
         unsigned char *vstring;
      };
      struct{
         int   vint;
      };
      struct{
         float  vfloat;
      };
   }
};

void clear(Value vall){
   if(vall.typ == 1){
      delete(vall.vstring);
   }else if(vall.typ == 2){
      delete(vall.vint);
   }else{
      delete(vall.vfloat);
   }
}
int main()
{
   struct Value v;
   /////////////////////////////////////////////
   v.typ=1;
   strcpy( v.vstring,"C Programming/may this a very big utf-8 string!");
   /*
   strcpy( v.vint,4); 
   strcpy( v.vfloat,4.5);
   */
   /////////////////////////////////////////////
   printf( "ValueType : %d\n", v.typ);
   printf( "ValueString : %s\n", v.vstring);
   printf( "ValueInt : %d\n", v.vint);
   printf( "ValueFloat : %f\n", v.vfloat);
   return 0;
   Value copy=v;
   clear(copy);
   copy.typ=2;
   copy.vint=5;
}
```

but this have bug , and i not know how can fix this.

this have a `Value` struct. in this have (vstring,vint,vfloat) , and type of value store in `typ` for fast speed.

*please help me to fix this code.*

i will want store this struct in array/map/hashmap....
tank you.

Comment: `unsigned char vstring`  should be  `unsigned char *vstring` and you need to assign memory first to copy string.

Comment: If it can be only one type at a time, you could use a [`union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union).

Comment: changed, but also again have errors.

Comment: what is `delete()`??? And how do you "delete" an int or a float?

Comment: delete() mean clear and delete from memory , i think can use `memset(<variable_name>, 0, MEMORY_BLOCK);` yes?   or `#define CLEAR(x) memset(x,'\0',1000);
CLEAR(<variable_name>);`?

Comment: this line: `void clear(Value vall){` will not compile with a message about an 'incomplete type'.  The line should be: `void clear( struct Value vall ){`

Comment: this line: `strcpy( v.vstring,"C Programming/may this a very big utf-8 string!");` is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event because the pointer `v.vstring` has not been set to point to any specific memory so will copy the string to what every place in memory is indicated by the uninitialized trash is on the stack where the struct is located.

Comment: please check my code : http://ideone.com/dF7c6T , line 39 have problem.

Comment: Suggest insert a code block similar to `v.vstring = malloc( 100 );  if( !v.vstring ) { perror( "malloc failed"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }` before the call to `strcpy()`  However, since the string is a literal, might just use a pointer, similar to: `v.vstring = "C Programming/may this a very big utf-8 string!";` rather than a call to `strcpy()`

Comment: you say strcpy in old code, may check new source file ? http://ideone.com/dF7c6T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might consider using a `union`. It's not required, but will save a few bytes:

```
struct Value {
   int typ;
   /*
   type=1  ==> get vstring
   type=2  ==> get int
   type=3  ==> get float
   */
   union {
    unsigned char *vstring;  // Changed to char pointer!!
    int   vint;
    float  vfloat;
   };
};
```

Next, when you copy the string, you need to allocate space:

```
const char *msg = "C Programming/may this a very big utf-8 string!";
struct Value v;
v.typ = 1;
v.vstring = malloc(strlen(msg) + 1);
strcpy(v.vstring, msg);
// strdup() does the same thing
```

And when you clear, you need to `free` that memory:

```
void clear(struct Value* vall){
   if (vall->typ == 1) {
      free(vall->vstring);
   }
   memset(vall, 0, sizeof(*vall));
}
```

Last, you can use an enum for the type, instead of "magic numbers":

```
enum VTYPE {VSTRING, VINT, VFLOAT};
typedef enum VTYPE vtype;
```

Also, here's a helper function to print:

```
void print_value(struct Value *v)
{
    static const char *types[] = {"VSTRING", "VINT", "VFLOAT"};
    printf( "ValueType : %s\n", v->typ >= 0 && v->typ < 3 ? types[v->typ] : "ERROR");
    if (VSTRING == v->typ) {
        printf( "ValueString : %s\n", v->vstring);
    }
    else if (VINT == v->typ) {
        printf( "ValueInt : %d\n", v->vint);
    }
    else if (VFLOAT == v->typ) {
        printf( "ValueFloat : %f\n", v->vfloat);
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the whole thing put together: http://ideone.com/ecy3qa

When you copy, be sure to duplicate the string:

```
void copy_value(struct Value *source, struct Value *dest) {
    if (VSTRING == source->typ) {
        dest->vstring = malloc(strlen(source->vstring) + 1);
        strcpy(dest->vstring, source->vstring);
    }
    else if (VINT == source->typ) {
        dest->vint = source->vint;
    }
    else if (VFLOAT == source->typ) {
        dest->vfloat = source->vfloat;
    }
    dest->typ = source->typ;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Tank you. :like:

Comment: tank you @johnny-mopp , also may add a copy of `v`? http://paste.ubuntu.com/24413409/ , after clear `v`, also copy deleted! this bad.

Comment: You have to be careful when copying. If the type is `VSTRING` you need to make a duplicate of the string. Updated answer with copy function.

Comment: i make `struct Value coppy()` in http://paste.ubuntu.com/24413473/ ,  please check this.

Comment: You are not duplicating the string here: `v_r.vstring=v->vstring;` With that you will have 2 different objects pointing to the same string.  So when you `clear(&v)`, `copy` will have an invalid pointer.

Comment: Done, tank you. :like:

Comment: Please if you have free time, answer another my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483396/how-substring-limit-using-c , tank you. good bye.

Comment: @GoWorkCode that q is closed so no answers can be added. But the posted answer notes, UTF-8 chars can be more than one byte. Maybe using [`wchar_t` strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) will help you.

Comment: tank you, i need `strlen()==>wcslen()` , `strcpy()==>??` for `w_char`. what name of funcs?

Comment: @GoWorkCode http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/C/0300__Wide-Character-String/WideCharacterFunctions.htm

Comment: ```wchar_t *msg_n = L"C Programming/may this a very big utf-8 string!DONE!سلام";
wprintf(L"%ls",msg_n);
``` how fix this code?

Comment: First, you have ideone setup for Java. Change the language to C. Next, because `wchar_t` is bigger, change `malloc`s to: `malloc((wcslen(msg) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));`  And when you use `wprintf` put an `L` in front of format string: `wprintf(L"ValueString : %s(%d)\n", v->vstring, v->size);`

Comment: `printf("%ls\n",v->vstring);` this is work in my source. but `wprintf` not work.

Comment: Yes, it's confusing. Try it on your pc. Also, reading this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816547/whats-the-difference-between-printfs-printfls-wprintfs-and-wp

Answer (score 0):

A proper version of your code (but note the comments!) is:

```
struct Value {
   int typ;
   /*
   type=1  ==> get vstring
   type=2  ==> get int
   type=3  ==> get float
   */
   union{
     unsigned char *vstring;
     int   vint;
     float  vfloat;
   } u;
};

void clear(struct Value *vall){
   if(vall->typ == 1){
      {free(vall->u.vstring); vall->u.vstring= 0;}
   }else if(vall->typ == 2){
      vall->u.vint=0;
   }else{
      vall->u.vfloat=0.0;
   }
}
int main()
{
   struct Value v;
   /////////////////////////////////////////////
   v.typ=1;
   v.u.vstring= malloc(strlen("C Programming/may this a very big utf-8 string!")+1);
   strcpy( v.u.vstring,"C Programming/may this a very big utf-8 string!");
   /////////////////////////////////////////////
   printf( "ValueType : %d\n", v.typ);
   printf( "ValueString : %s\n", v.u.vstring);
   printf( "ValueInt : %d\n", v.u.vint);        // <== there is no int in u
   printf( "ValueFloat : %f\n", v.u.vfloat);    // <== there is no float in u
   return 0;
   struct Value copy=v; // <== you cannot do this as you now use the memory of the vstring
   clear(&copy);    // <== this now releases the memory of vstring in both 'copy' and 'v'
   copy.typ=2;
   copy.u.vint=5;
}
```

Comment: tank you, but also have error in gcc. http://paste.ubuntu.com/24413365/

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` and add the keyword `struct` before `Value` (it is a `struct Value`). I'll update the solution with the latter.